# How to reset jQuery dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following js code to load menu from other website. Problem is it loads the html fine but its menu's (not working like dropdown etc) js is not applying and menus are not working but css does. How can I reset DOM? or would be work around that I may run local js for the menus that's added in the file?

Let me know if I am not clear.

```
var $fetch = jQuery.noConflict();

$fetch(document).ready(function () { 
$fetch.ajax({
        url: 'test.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (res) {
            var data = $fetch(res.responseText);
            $fetch(".region.region-header #menu-fetched").html(data);               
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You can't unless you store the initial DOM state. You'd have to refresh.

Comment: Look at event delegation, which is what you need to use to bind events to future elements. `$(document).on('click', '#menu-fetched li a', function(){ ... });` for example.

Comment: Before running `fetch()`, you'd assign the results of `$('#menu-fetched').html()` to a variable, which you could then use later.

Comment: That said, I'd delay load of the new menu items until the remote JS loads.

Comment: js is local but html is dynamic loads from other website.

Comment: @AamirShahzad it seems that you're loading content after running jQuery, which is why you need to use event delegation. If you post the jQuery that you expected to be bound to those elements, I can show you how to fix it,

Comment: Edit your question, adding the jquery that affects the elements that you're loading dynamically.